# Main title and legend.position issue on ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am having issues on how to position the main title and legend in ggplotly. I would like my main title to be on the top of the graph and left aligned. I would also like my legend to be at the bottom center of the graph

Here is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)

Month_Names <- c("2010-11","2010-12",
             "2011-01","2011-02","2011-03","2011-04","2011-05","2011-06","2011-07","2011-08","2011-09","2011-10","2011-11","2011-12",
             "2012-01","2012-02","2012-03","2012-04","2012-05","2012-06","2012-07","2012-08","2012-09","2012-10","2012-11","2012-12",
             "2013-01","2013-02","2013-03","2013-04","2013-05","2013-06","2013-07","2013-08","2013-09","2013-10","2013-11","2013-12",
             "2014-01","2014-02","2014-03","2014-04","2014-05","2014-06","2014-07","2014-08","2014-09","2014-10","2014-11","2014-12",
             "2015-01","2015-02","2015-03","2015-04","2015-05","2015-06","2015-07","2015-08","2015-09","2015-10","2015-11","2015-12",
             "2016-01","2016-02","2016-03","2016-04","2016-05","2016-06","2016-07","2016-08","2016-09","2016-10","2016-11","2016-12",
             "2017-01")
Actual_volume <- c(54447,57156,
               52033,49547,58718,53109,56488,60095,54683,60863,56692,55283,55504,56633,
               53267,52587,54680,55569,60013,56985,59709,61281,54188,59832,56489,55819,
               59295,52692,56663,59698,61232,57694,63111,60473,58984,64050,54957,63238,
               59460,54430,58901,61088,60496,62984,66895,62720,65591,67815,58289,72002,
               61054,60329,69283,68002,63196,72267,71058,69539,71379,70925,68704,76956,
               65863,70494,77348,70214,74770,77480,69721,83034,76761,77927,79768,81836,
               75381)

df_data <- data.frame(Month_Names, Actual_volume) 

trendDateRange1 <- c("2010-11-01", "2017-01-31")
trendDateRange2 <- c("2012-01-01", "2012-12-31")
trendDateRange3 <- c("2013-01-01", "2013-12-31")
numoftrends <- 3

trends <- data_frame(Start = c("2010-11", "2012-01", "2013-01"),
                 End = c("2017-01", "2012-12", "2013-12"))
combined_data <- df_data %>%
                 crossing(trends) %>%
                 mutate(Month_Names = as.character(Month_Names),
TrendName = paste(Start, End, sep = "-")) %>%
filter(Month_Names >= Start,
     Month_Names <= End)


p <- ggplot(combined_data, aes(Month_Names, y = Actual_volume,
                      group = TrendName,
                      color = TrendName)) +
     geom_line() +
     labs(x=" ",y=" ") +
     labs(title = "New plot title") +
     theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="blue", 
                      size=18, 
                              margin = margin(10, 0, 10, 0)),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
 )

print(ggplotly(p))
```

Answer (score 6):

I didn't find any solution for the title problem. See if this will help you regarding the legend.

```
p <- ggplot(combined_data, aes(Month_Names, y = Actual_volume,
                           group = TrendName,
                           color = TrendName)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x=" ",y=" ") +
  labs(title = "New plot title") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="blue", 
                              size=18, 
                              margin = margin(10, 0, 10, 0)),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    #axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank()
  )

ggplotly(p) %>% 
  layout(title = "New plot title",
     #xaxis = list(showticklabels = FALSE),
     legend = list(orientation = "h",
                   y = 0, x = 0))
```

Comment: Thank you Rafael Cunha for your time in looking into this. However when I run your code I got an error stating : "Error in lengths(x$annotations) : 'x' must be a list." Am I missing in something?

Comment: I don't have any idea about this error. Try to clear your environment and run the first part of your code until `filter(Month_Names >= Start,
     Month_Names <= End)` and then run the part i've posted

Comment: I cleared my environment several times and ran it as you suggested and I still am getting this error. Have you tried running it on your end? I am running this on R Studio 1.0.136. Thanks

Comment: I ran more than once. I closed my RStudio, opened again, ran again. Very weird. I don't know if it's a problem with the version of RStudio (mine's 0.99.903)

Comment: Hi Rafael - I added the annonations = list() to your code. It ran however I need my axis.text.x to be displayed on the graph. Here is the code that I have changed.   ggplotly(p) %>% 
  layout(title = "New plot title",
         #xaxis = list(showticklabels = FALSE),
         legend = list(orientation = "h",
                       y = 0, x = 0),  annotations = list())

Comment: If you need the axis.text.x just remove `axis.text.x = element_blank()` from `p` code. And you can play with the position of the legend with the y value in the layout. For example `ggplotly(p) %>% layout(title = "New plot title", legend = list(orientation = "h", y = -.132, x = 0), annotations = list())`

Comment: Thanks Rafael Cunha. Have a great day!